# Ogre with Qt QML

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, ogre

I have been trying to implement Ogre in Qt thanks to QMLOgre to make a viewer. Everything is working correctly when I am doing everything in Ogre's thread, for example, it loads ogrehead.mesh on Ogre's initialization.

The problem is that when I'm trying to load models when clicking in the User Interface, the functions are executed in Qt's UI thread and the model loading results in an exception (and eventually a crash) because it can't create the associated Vertex Buffer.

I went for a Mutex-Condition-Queue system so the UI would add "Actions to do" in the queue, and during the frame update, I'd read the queue and execute each command.
I don't think this implementation is pretty, as I have to make a special Message struct for each command of the viewer (Load model, Import Model, Save Model, Load Material etc...).

Is there a way to make this any prettier/more maintainable?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure there is a concept of a dedicated "ogre thread". I would say that Ogre just uses the thread you used to initialize it, and if that happens to be the main thread you propably don't have a threading issue. Have you checked if it might be more of a opengl shared context problem? I tried to use QMLOgre and it didn't worked at all. Ogre and a QML scene with one text line, was just an ogre scene with reset transformation and a none readable line of blocks(guess that was supposed to be the text in qml).